# How to add NameSpace/PrefixMap in Apache Jena Model?

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, apache-jena

I don't know why after setting setNsPrefix of Model it doesn't work according to my expectation.
This is my **Java Code**

```
public class TestClass
{
   public static void main(String[] args){
     Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
     model.setNsPrefix("vocab","http://myweb.in/vocab#");         
     model.createResource().addLiteral(ResourceFactory.createProperty("vocab:name"),"Dhannan");
     String query
                = " SELECT * "
                + " WHERE { "
                + " ?Subject ?Predicate ?Object . "
                + " } ";
     Services.executeQuery(model, query);
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
--------------------------------------
| Subject | Predicate    | Object    |
======================================
| _:b0    | <vocab:name> | "Dhannan" |
--------------------------------------
```

**Expected :**

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Subject | Predicate                    | Object    |
======================================================
| _:b0    | <http://myweb.in/vocab#name> | "Dhannan" |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Where did I make mistake?
From my thought setNsPrefix can do that .

Answer (score 1):

Setting prefixes does not turn it on in the API. That isn't provided, especially for `ResourceFactory.createProperty` as there is no model at that point.

Expand the prefixed name with `model.expandPrefix` to get the full URI, the use that URI.

Comment: Sorry but it is not working . I added model.expandPrefix("vocab");
System.out.println(model.expandPrefix("vocab"));                                        But it is still showing "vocab:name" and even after printing it is showing "vocab".

Comment: while this System.out.println(model.shortForm("http://myweb.in/vocab#")); gives me shortForm "vocab:"

Comment: Sorry I have to do this System.out.println(model.expandPrefix("vocab:"));    It works fine and give me "http://myweb.in/vocab#". But still I have question , can we avoid again and again writing this resource.addLiteral(ResourceFactory.createProperty(model.expandPrefix("vocab:")+"name"),"Dhannan");

Comment: (1) `model.expandPrefix("vocab:name")` (2) create constants for your vocabulary (see the classes in the "vocabaulary" package) and don't make a property every time.

Comment: You can always create a small static helper function to make things the way you want to.